# Laravel UserTableSeeder Error --seed after Voyager installation

Tags: laravel, migration, seed, voyager

Hi i am new in laravel and i set up my installation and added the voyager package. now when i try to refresh my database CLI: `php artisan migrate:refresh --seed` and i get this error message.

```
Migrated:  2018_01_24_120417_create_voucher_table
Migrating: 2018_01_29_094240_create_shop_table
Migrated:  2018_01_29_094240_create_shop_table
Migrating: 2018_01_30_085852_create_categorys_table
Migrated:  2018_01_30_085852_create_categorys_table
Seeding: UsersTableSeeder

In Builder.php line 412:

No query results for model [TCG\Voyager\Models\Role].
```

Where i can find a detailed error description and what is wrong with the seed ?

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use TCG\Voyager\Models\Role;
use TCG\Voyager\Models\User;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Auto generated seed file.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        if (User::count() == 0) {
            $role = Role::where('name', 'admin')->firstOrFail();

            User::create([
                'name'           => 'Admin',
                'email'          => 'admin@admin.com',
                'password'       => bcrypt('password'),
                'remember_token' => str_random(60),
                'role_id'        => $role->id,
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias

Comment: $role is empty!

Comment: it makes no sense to me why there is no seed for the role model

Answer (score 1):

Did you run `php artisan voyager:install --with-dummy`? This command create all the tables and roles you need to start working with Voyager

Comment: if i run this every time when i want to refresh migations than i will lose the breads..

Answer (score 0):

Create the role in the run() function:

```
public function run()
{
    if (Role::count() == 0) {
        Role::create([
            'name'           => 'admin',
            'display_name'   => 'Administrator',
        ]);
    }
    if (User::count() == 0) {
        $role = Role::where('name', 'admin')->firstOrFail();

        User::create([
            'name'           => 'Admin',
            'email'          => 'admin@admin.com',
            'password'       => bcrypt('password'),
            'remember_token' => Str::random(60),
            'role_id'        => $role->id,
        ]);
    }
}
```